# How can I reload HTML table after AJAX success on Django web page?

Tags: ajax, django, html-table, reload

I'm using two datepickers from the jQuery library for start and end dates. Once I have the two dates I send them to my django view via ajax. I then run the model query in my views which will return a filtered dict into my django context. My question now is how can I reload the table on the template?

Would I have to define a Javascript function to load a table and call it on ajax success? Or perhaps a better way?

html

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
<tr>
    <th>Start Date: <input id="mail_start_date"/></th>
    <th>End Date: <input id="mail_end_date"/></th>
    <th><button id='btn'>Filter</button></th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th>Desk</th>
  <th># of Packages</th>
</tr>
{% for desk, count in pick_dict.items %}
<tr>
  <td>{{desk}}</td>
  <td>{{count}}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Javascript

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
$('#mail_start_date').datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd" });
$('#mail_end_date').datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd" });

$('#btn').click(function(){
  var start = $('#mail_start_date').val();
  var end = $('#mail_end_date').val();
  $.ajax({
    url: "/apps/centraldesk/mail/stats/",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
      'start': start,
      'end': end,
      csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}',
    },
    success: "SOMTHING NEEDS TO HAPPEN HRERE"
  });
});
```

views.py

```
def mail_stats(request):
  pick_dict = {}
  if request.is_ajax():
    pick_start = request.POST['start']
    pick_end = request.POST['end']
    pick_start = str(pick_start)
    pick_end = str(pick_end)

    in_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(pick_start, "%Y-%I-%d")
    out_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(pick_end, "%Y-%I-%d")

    pick_list = MailRecord.objects.filter(timeIn__range=(pick_start, pick_end))
    for item in pick_list:
      if pick_dict.has_key(item.desk.name):
        pick_dict[item.desk.name] += 1
      else:
        pick_dict[item.desk.name] = 1

  context = {
    "mail_list" : mail_list,
    "pick_dict" : pick_dict,
  }
  return render("mail_stats.html", context, context_instance=RequestContext(request, processors=[custom_proc]))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you define a javascript function, like so

```
...
},
success: function(json) {
  // Access your table here and manipulate it with the returned data from "json" (json is the dictionary given by your django view)
}
});
...
```

You could also add an error-function next to the success function.